# Is it possible to know what are applications/clients are using my nuget package

Tags: nuget, package

This question is bit strange.i am curious to know is there any way to know what all applications/clients are using my nuget package.

i have published few nuget packages. i can able to see only statistics provided by nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, you can't.

But if your package name is unique, and you are interested in public projects on github, then you can search for something like:

`PackageReference Include="Your.Package.Name"`

or

`dependency id="Your.Package.Name"`

This might give you some results.